# help understanding how $\ln$ and $e$ cancel.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I realise cancel may be the wrong term and inverse may be more appropriate but these is one situation I really don't get…or rather haven't found a suitable explanation. Most sources I have come across just show you how to do it but not why it is working the way it is.

Made up example:
Solve for $x$

$\ln(3+x) = 9$

$e^{\ln(3+x)} = e^9$

$3+x = e^9$

$x = e^9-3$

But what I don't get is where $e$ has been added to each side.

The first line ($\ln(3+x) = 9$) to me reads as "$e$ to the power of something equals $3 + x$ . That something is $9$, therefore $e^9 = 3+x$.

Then we move on and add $e$ to each side . $e^{\ln(3+x)} = e^9$

This part reads to me as saying the exponent on the left hand side is $e$ to the power of something equals $3 + x$. Based on our previous line we know this something is $9$. Therefore $e^9 = e^9$ …but I knew that already from the first line …(didn't I work that out ? or am I mistaken )

Now where I get confused is where the $e$ and $\ln$ on the left hand side cancel out. I am trying to work out a way how one would explain this cancelation in in words. I know how to do it in terms of writing it down but that doesn't mean I understand it. It is the understanding that I am trying to build.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\large{e^{\ln(3+x)} = e^9}$ means, $\large{e^{\ln_e(3+x)} = e^9}$ and it is a logarithmic property that that, $\large{x^{log_xy}=y}$, therefore $e$ on the LHS "cancels" out.

Comment: e^ln(3+x) just in this part alone I don't understand how this side of the equation results in (3+x), when I read it and work it out I keep getting the answer as e^9 on the left and right hand side. The cancellation between e and ln has me confused

Comment: @user3754366 You know the property $\large{x^{log_xy}=y}$, just replace $x$ with $e$ and $y$ with $3+x$ and you will get your solution.

Comment: ahhh..so I had been discarding the 3+x as my answer on the LH side as I knew that 3+x = e^9 and as a result I was just writing  e^9 = e^9. But, because I want to solve for x I need to keep x=3 alive in the equation so to speak otherwise I won't be able to save for x.

Comment: yes !!!${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second equation $e^{ln(3+x)} = e^9$. Just use the logarithm property
$$log_b a = x \Rightarrow b^x = a.$$

Comment: Ohhh I didn't realise this was an extra step. I was just copying the method from our class notes.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the uniqueness of functions. Whenever $a=b$ it must also be true that 
$f(a)=f(b)$ for any function $f$. So in your example, if $a=\ln (3+x)$ and $b=9$ then 
$e^{\ln (3+x)}=e^a=e^b=e^9$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By definition, $x=\log_ac$ is the solution to $a^x=c$. Basically, unlike the previous operations, exponentiation is not commutative, so, in general, $a^b\neq b^a$. Therefore, when dealing with equations of the form $a^b=c$, we have two cases: if *b* and *c* are known, then $a=\sqrt[\Large b]c$ . On the other hand, if *a* and *c* are known, then $b=\log_ac$.

Comment: I can work through and follow what you've written but am unsure where I should be going with it.

Comment: By definition, $\ln=\log_{~\large e}$.